# Spring cloud Kafka does infinite retry when it fails

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

Currently, I am having an issue where one of the consumer functions throws an error which makes Kafka retry the records again and again.

```
@Bean
public Consumer<List<RuleEngineSubject>> processCohort() {
    return personDtoList -> {
        
        for(RuleEngineSubject subject : personDtoList)
            processSubject(subject);

    };
}
```

This is the consumer the `processSubject` throws a custom error which causes it to fail.

```
processCohort-in-0:
  destination: internal-process-cohort
  consumer:
    max-attempts: 1
    batch-mode: true
    concurrency: 10
  group: process-cohort-group
```

The above is my binder for Kafka.

Currently, I am attempting to retry 2 times and then send to a dead letter queue but I have been unsuccessful and not sure which is the right approach to take.

I have tried to implement a custom handler that will handle the error when it fails but does not retry again and I am not sure how to send to a dead letter queue

```
   @Bean
ListenerContainerCustomizer<AbstractMessageListenerContainer<?, ?>> customizer() {

    return (container, dest, group) -> {
        if (group.equals("process-cohort-group")) {
            container.setBatchErrorHandler(new BatchErrorHandler() {
                @Override
                public void handle(Exception thrownException, ConsumerRecords<?, ?> data) {
                    System.out.println(data.records(dest).iterator().);
                    data.records(dest).forEach(r -> {
                        System.out.println(r.value());
                    });
                    System.out.println("failed payload='{}'" + thrownException.getLocalizedMessage());
                }
            });
        }
      
    };

}
```

This stops infinite retry but does not send a dead letter queue. Can I get suggestions on how to retry two times and then send a dead letter queue. From my understanding batch listener does not how to recover when there is an error, could someone help shine light on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure a suitable error handler in the listener container; you can disable retry and dlq in the binding and use a `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer` instead. See the answer [Retry max 3 times when consuming batches in Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Binder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69175145/retry-max-3-times-when-consuming-batches-in-spring-cloud-stream-kafka-binder/69178434#69178434)

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only one LastSubscriberMessageHandler is allowed. Received this error when implementing do you happen to know why?

Comment: Probably unrelated - ask a new question with a [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

Retry 15 times then throw it to topicname.DLT topic

```
@Bean
      public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
            new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setCommonErrorHandler(
            new DefaultErrorHandler(
                new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(kafkaTemplate()), kafkaBackOffPolicy()));
        factory.setConsumerFactory(kafkaConsumerFactory());
        return factory;
      }
    
@Bean
      public ExponentialBackOffWithMaxRetries kafkaBackOffPolicy() {
        var exponentialBackOff = new ExponentialBackOffWithMaxRetries(15);
        exponentialBackOff.setInitialInterval(Duration.ofMillis(500).toMillis());
        exponentialBackOff.setMultiplier(2);
        exponentialBackOff.setMaxInterval(Duration.ofSeconds(2).toMillis());
        return exponentialBackOff;
      }
```